# Sample User Data for multiple test across parallel workers in Playwright

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

I have a use case for testing authentication functionality where there are multiple test cases like login into an app, forgetting a password, log in to MFA-enabled applications. I have a set of multiple users that can be used in any of the test cases but then the issue arises when trying to run them in multiple browser contexts. I have stored my test data in a JSON file with the username and password of multiple sample users.

When let's say test runs for login to MFA enabled application, all three browser worker is launched simultaneously and all of them try to get user details from the test data file.

BUT the issue comes here, all of them picked up the first object let's say user A, all three browser test passes till the password step but when MFA is entered, it creates a race condition, the one worker who submitted the OTP first will pass but the rest fails because that 30 seconds window OTP is already redeemed.

I want to have a way that works in the same way as the synchronized method in Java where if a worker is using one user, don't make them available for another user, instead provide them next user from the test data.

Please guide me on how to do that in Playwright!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are far more elegant ways of doing this, but one approach is to use the worker index / parallel index feature described in the docs here:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#worker-index-and-parallel-index

It looks like parallel index may be a better fit for your use case.

If each of your rows of test data includes the index of the worker it is intended for, then your code can ensure that worker 0 only picks up worker 0's test data and worker 1 picks up worker 1's test data.

Alternatively you could use testConfig.workers to determine how many workers there are and then use the remainer/modulo operator (%) in JS to split the rows up between the different workers:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-workers

So you would compare `TestDataRowNumber % testConfig.workers` to `process.env.TEST_PARALLEL_INDEX` to split the file up amongst however many workers you had.